# HTTP POST with a file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am new to javascript/protractor and am trying to write code that posts or uploads a text file to a REST endpoint, somewhat, on the following lines. I am not able to get this to work and do not know why it is failing. Can anyone please validate this or suggest a better solution, preferably with sample code. (I have checked online and found lot of information, but was not able to apply any of that directly.)

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');   
var form = new FormData();
    form.append('agency', 'California');
    form.append('siteType', 'EF');
    fileName = "test.txt";
    var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../resources/upload/" + fileName);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath,
                     "This is a test txt file");

    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(absolutePath));

    request.post({url: restServiceUrl, formData: form},
    function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('upload failed:', err);
          }
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
         });
```

Comment: xhr.send(formData), I'm not sure your require('request') also use it.

Comment: @Nicol, Trying using XmlHttpRequest as per your comment. Can you tell me how to append a text file to FormData object ?

Comment: The file must be selected by user ,read from path,not allow,any browser.